# How to test this class with mockito?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, mockito, jwt

I implemented REST API using JWT token.  User can signup new account, or login with username & password.  I have a class called   AuthController.   I need to test two methods: login/register.  I wanna use Mockito to test this class.

How to mock authentication(token)?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/auth")
public class AuthController {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final JwtTokenUtils jwtToken;
    private final UserService userService;
    private final UserRepository repository;
    private final PasswordEncoder encoder;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, JwtTokenUtils jwtToken, UserService userService, UserRepository repository, PasswordEncoder encoder, RoleRepository roleRepository) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.jwtToken = jwtToken;
        this.userService = userService;
        this.repository = repository;
        this.encoder = encoder;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }
```

Method: /login

```
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody AuthDto requestDto) {
        try {
            String username = requestDto.getUsername();
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(requestDto.getUsername(), requestDto.getPassword()));
            User user=userService.findByUsername(username);

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            String jwt = jwtToken.generateJwtToken(authentication);

            UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
            List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                    .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponseDto(
                    jwt,
                    userDetails.getId(),
                    userDetails.getUsername(),
                    userDetails.getEmail(),
                    roles));

        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password");
        }
    }
```

Method:/signUp

```
    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody CustomerDto signUpAuthDto) {
        if (repository.existsByUsername(signUpAuthDto.getUsername())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken"));
        }
        if (repository.existsByEmail(signUpAuthDto.getEmail())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Email is already in use"));
        }
        if (signUpAuthDto.getPassword() !=null && !signUpAuthDto.getPassword().equals(signUpAuthDto.getConfirm())) {
            return  ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Error: You entered two different passwords. Please try again"));
        }

        User user = new User(signUpAuthDto.getUsername(),
                signUpAuthDto.getEmail(),
                encoder.encode(signUpAuthDto.getPassword()));
                encoder.encode(signUpAuthDto.getConfirm());

        Set<Role> strRoles = signUpAuthDto.getRole();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if (strRoles == null) {
            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(EnumRole.ROLE_USER)
                    .orElseThrow(()-> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found"));
            roles.add(userRole);
        } else {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                if ("admin".equals(role)) {
                    Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(EnumRole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                            .orElseThrow(()-> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found"));

                    roles.add(adminRole);
                } else {
                    Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(EnumRole.ROLE_USER)
                            .orElseThrow(()-> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found"));
                    roles.add(userRole);
                }
            });
        }

        user.setRoles(roles);
        repository.save(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));

    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to mock authentication here is using one of the `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors` of the Spring Security Test dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

So your Spring MVC controllers you can write a test with `@WebMvcTest` and get an auto-configured `MockMvc` instance.

This way you test your endpoint with a mocked Servlet environment and you can mock any authentication or logged-in user you want.

```
this.mockMvc
    .perform(
      post("/api/auth/signup")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content("YOUR_PAYLOAD")
        .with(csrf())
        .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user("duke"))
    )
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
```

More information about this in the following [MockMvc guide](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-mockmvc/).

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the information.